# Timestamp in .NET

Tags: .net, timestamp

I have to work with dates and times in my .NET project, and one of the things I need to do is get the current date and add 2 weeks onto it, and if the date the user entered is after those two weeks throw out an error. Or, if the date they entered is before the current date throw out another error.

Now, I know how to do this, but not with the way .NET seems to handle dates. I have only actually worked with timestamps in the past (probably because everything I've done in the past has been on Unix) and .NET doesn't seem to have a timestamp way of handling the date or time.

Can anyone tell me how I would go about this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean equivalent of sql timestamp in .NET ?

Comment: Your question is kind of vague. Do you want to know how to use the `DateTime` class, or how to work with Unix timestamps? Or something completely different?

Comment: The question is clear enough, how to validate that a user-input is inside a 14 day window.

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime value = ...your code...
DateTime today = DateTime.Today, max = today.AddDays(14);
if(value < today || value > max) {
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
}
```

One key point: only access `Now` / `Today` *once* in a related check - otherwise you can get some very freaky results just on the stroke of midnight. An extreme edge-case, maybe...

Answer (score 1):

There's the `DateTime` class in .NET, but I don't really know what you mean by ".NET doesn't have a timestamp way of handling the date." Do you mean a way to generate or work with Unix timestamps?

To convert a Unix timestamp to a DateTime, you could do this:

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
epoch = epoch.AddSeconds(timestamp);
```

To add two weeks, you would use the `AddDays` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
            // Whatever class is able to retrieve the date the user just entered
            DateTime userDateTime = Whatever.GetUserDateTime();
            if (userDateTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(14))
                throw new Exception("The date cannot be after two weeks from now");
            else if (userDateTime < DateTime.Now)
                throw new Exception("The date cannot be before now");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use

```
if (objUserDate.Date > DateTime.Today.AddDays(14))
{
     //Error 1
}
else if (objUserDate.Date < DateTime.Today)
{
    //Error 2
}
```

Comment: +1 For using DateTime.Today. If the time of day isn't relevant, it shouldn't be included in the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

```
var userInputDate = DateTime.Parse(someInput);

if(userInputDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(14)) throw new ApplicationException("Dont like dates after 2 weeks of today");
if(userInputDate < DateTime.Now) throw new ApplicationException("Date shouldnt be before now, for some reason");
```

Answer (score 0):

i would probably have something like this:

```
DateTime twoWeeksFromNow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14);

if(enteredDateTime > twoWeeksFromNow)
{
    throw "ERROR!!!";
}
```